# What's the best way of achieving common tasks from within a Vuex store

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently trying to achieve a common task when making API calls from within a Vuex store action object, my action currently looks like this:

```js
/**
 * check an account activation token
 *
 */
[CHECK_ACTIVATION_TOKEN] ({commit}, payload) {
  Api.checkActivationToken(payload.token).then((response) => {
    if (response.fails()) {
      return commit('NEW_MESSAGE', {message: responses.activation[response.code]})
    }

    return commit('SET_TOKEN')
  })
}
```

I have several such methods carrying out various actions. What I want to be able to do is present a loader when each API call is made, and hide it again once the response is received. I can achieve this like so:

```js
/**
 * check an account activation token
 *
 */
[CHECK_ACTIVATION_TOKEN] ({commit}, payload) {
  commit('SHOW_LOADER')
  Api.checkActivationToken(payload.token).then((response) => {
    commit('HIDE_LOADER')
    if (response.fails()) {
      return commit('NEW_MESSAGE', {message: responses.activation[response.code]})
    }

    return commit('SET_TOKEN')
  })
}
```

But I would need to repeat these SHOW_LOADER/HIDE_LOADER commits in each API call.

What I would like to do is centralise this functionality somewhere so that whenever API calls are made the showing and hiding of the loader is implicitly bound to the calls and not have to include these additional lines each time.

For clarity; the instantiated API is a client layer that sits on top of Axios so that I can prepare the call before firing it off. I've found I can't directly import the store into the client layer or where the Axios events are fired (so that I could centralise the loader visibility there) because Im instantiating the client layer within the vuex module and therefore creates a circular reference when I tried to do so, meaning the store is returned as undefined.

Is what I am trying to do possible through some hook or event that I have yet to come across?

Comment: You can create a 'central' action where you `commit` loading/loaded mutations. This action can receive another action name (string) as an argument. Inbetween your 'loading' commits you can `dispatch` your action passed as an argument. But for async tasks the closing commit won't work as intended. I suppose you can make it work if your actions return a Promise so that you can call closing commit in a callback.

Comment: Yes I believe this is what I have currently, where the module for the loader accepts the string SHOW / HIDE when called but I still need to make these calls "manually" each time. I need to give the API access to the store either by explicitly passing it through each time (which does not solve the problem) or by some other hook that binds the SHOW/HIDE to the event. I've yet to find an efficient way of doing either of these things.

Answer (score 1):

I actually took a different path with this "issue" after reading [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/221#issuecomment-228234609) GitHub thread and response from Evan You where he talks about decoupling.

Ultimately I decided that by forcing the API layer to have direct knowledge of the store I am tightly coupling the two things together. Therefore I now handle the SHOW and HIDE feature I was looking for in each of the components where the store commits are made, like so:

```js
/**
     * check the validity of the reset token
     *
     */
    checkToken () {
      if (!this.token) {
        return this.$store.commit('NEW_MESSAGE', {message: 'No activation token found. Unable to continue'})
      }

      this.showLoader()

      this.$store.dispatch('CHECK_ACTIVATION_TOKEN', {token: this.token}).then(this.hideLoader)
    },
```

Here I have defined methods that shortcut the Vuex commits in a Master vue component that each of my components will extend. I then call showLoader when needed and use the promise to determine when the process is complete and call hideLoader there.

This means I have removed presentation logic from both the store and the API layer and kept them where they, arguably, logically belong.

If anyone has any better thoughts on this I'm all ears.

@wostex - thanks for your response!

Comment: This seems to be a better approach in your case, thanks for sharing. I think it depends on a project though. For example, I made an app where several components inject a 'loading status' getter to decide which templates/icons to show at the moment. The 'loading status' is set by an action which makes an expensive API call. In this case it's better to place 'loading' commits inside an action, as they depend on this action and it's less code than comitting the same mutation out of many components.

Comment: Yeah having slept on it Im coming back to the thinking you suggest. Having all of the commits to do with the thing you are doing encapsulated within the action seems more appropriate than having them repeated (and scattered) throughout the components. I think Im going to go down this route and see how it pans out.